# App Gives Error in Simulator but works fine on Device

Tags: xcode, simulator

App works fine on Device but i cant find reason why i get this many error s when building for simulator.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIFontDescriptor", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FBNotifications(FBNCardFont.o)
"_UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute", referenced from:
  _FBNCardFontWithNameSize in FBNotifications(FBNCardFont.o)
"_UIFontDescriptorFaceAttribute", referenced from:
  _FBNCardFontWithNameSize in FBNotifications(FBNCardFont.o)
"_UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification", referenced from:
  +[ANSLifecycleEvent notificationNameMap] in Crashlytics(ANSLifecycleEvent.o)
  -[ANSAnswersController registerForApplicationLifecycleEvents] in Crashlytics(ANSAnswersController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableParagraphStyle", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKButton.o)
  objc-class-ref in FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginButton.o)
"_UIPasteboardNameFind", referenced from:
  ___78-[FBSDKBridgeAPIProtocolNativeV1 _JSONStringForObject:enablePasteboard:error:]_block_invoke in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKBridgeAPIProtocolNativeV1.o)
"_UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
  -[FBSDKWebDialog _addObservers] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKWebDialog.o)
  -[FBSDKWebDialog _removeObservers] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKWebDialog.o)
  -[CLSCrashReportingController setupStateNotifications] in Crashlytics(CLSCrashReportingController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSParagraphStyle", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FBNotifications(FBNCardTextContent.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITableViewHeaderFooterView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTAppearance.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UITableViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DGTContactsInvitationViewController in DigitsKit(DGTContactsInvitationViewController.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIImageView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DGTLogoImageView in DigitsKit(DGTLogoImageView.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UITextView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DGTFootnoteLabel in DigitsKit(DGTFootnoteLabel.o)
"_UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric", referenced from:
  -[DGTLogoImageView intrinsicContentSize] in DigitsKit(DGTLogoImageView.o)
  -[DGTHairlineView intrinsicContentSize] in DigitsKit(DGTHairlineView.o)
"_UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey", referenced from:
  -[DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView dgt_keyboardWillShow:] in DigitsKit(DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.o)
"_UIAccessibilityTraitButton", referenced from:
  -[GIDSignInButton sharedInit] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignInButton_97bfaf741496a97236fa3739518a0583.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UISearchController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUICountryTableViewController.o)
  objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTCountryTableViewController.o)
  objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTContactsInvitationViewController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UILocalizedIndexedCollation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUICollationForCountries.o)
  objc-class-ref in DigitsKit(DGTCollationForCountries.o)
"_UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey", referenced from:
  -[FUIPhoneVerificationViewController keyboardWasShown:] in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUIPhoneVerificationViewController.o)
  -[FUIPhoneVerificationViewController keyboardWillBeHidden:] in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUIPhoneVerificationViewController.o)
  -[DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView dgt_keyboardWillShow:] in DigitsKit(DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.o)
  -[DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView dgt_keyboardWillHide:] in DigitsKit(DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.o)
"_UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey", referenced from:
  -[FUIPhoneVerificationViewController keyboardWasShown:] in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUIPhoneVerificationViewController.o)
  -[FUIPhoneVerificationViewController keyboardWillBeHidden:] in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUIPhoneVerificationViewController.o)
  -[DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView dgt_keyboardWillShow:] in DigitsKit(DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.o)
  -[DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView dgt_keyboardWillHide:] in DigitsKit(DGTKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.o)
"_UIKeyboardDidShowNotification", referenced from:
  -[FUIPhoneVerificationViewController registerForKeyboardNotifications] in FirebasePhoneAuthUI(FUIPhoneVerificationViewController.o)
"_UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey", referenced from:
  -[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy initWithApplication:] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy_d84ca069394368ea9e8127dbd13cc324.o)
  -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:openURL:options:] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
```

Working on XCode 9.2 and iOS 11.2 running on simulator shows this all issues. in device it works fine.

can someone guide me what I am missing.

Comment: This error message is incomplete. There is something missing from the top.

Comment: @ThomasW Editted.

Comment: It is a link error. For some reason it isn't finding the iOS x86 symbols. You probably need to describe your project settings.

Comment: @ThomasW can you please tell me what Project Settings I need to describe.